# Why can't I change a global variable in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

I have a global variable let's just call it:

```
foo = ""
```

And I have a bunch of functions, and I called foo in one of those function. I changed it to having a string value. But if I go into another function after that and call it it doesn't still have that string value.

Here's an example:

```
foo = ""

funct():
   global foo
   foo = "some words"

funct2():
   global foo
   if foo == "some words":
       print ("foo is" + foo) 

funct()
funct2()
```

But in my case, in:

```
funct2()
```

it thinks that foo is empty even though in

```
funct()
```

I changed it to having a value, is it possible that nested functions have an effect on this because my code is very large and I couldn't really accurately depict the function mess in it. So instead I gave you this example, where here it is quite simple. Do nested functions not work well with changing globals or is there another problem. Is there an easier way to get one variable that can be read and edited in any function? Thank you for anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Comment: This code has no nested functions.

Comment: It is also not valid Python, so it doesn't run at all. Please post the actual code you're having a problem with.

Comment: This code, after adding `def` to each function definition, works as you'd expect.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code worked fine for me on Python 3.6.1 on Linux. (That is, of course, after fixing the syntax related errors).

Comment: Well my code is 1596 lines so I can't really.

Comment: I know that one works but it's an example! to give you the idea of what the problem i'm having is, my problem isn't that code. that code is an example to show you what the idea of the problem is.